# How to document functions with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, standards, documentation-generation, jsdoc

JSDoc doesn't seem to pick up on most of my functions. Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Function one.
 */
(function one() {
    /**
     * Function two.
     */
    function two() {
        /**
         * Function three.
         */
        function three() {
        }
    }
})();

var four = {
    /**
     * Function five/six.
     */
    five: function six() {
    },
    /**
     * Function seven/eight.
     */
    seven: function eight() {
    },
};

nine.ten = {
    /**
     * Function eleven/twelve.
     */
    eleven: function twelve() {
        /**
         * Function thirteen/fourteen.
         */
        var thirteen = function fourteen() {
        };
    },
    /**
     * Function fifteen/sixteen.
     */
    fifteen: function sixteen() {
    },
};

/**
 * Function eighteen
 */
seventeen(function eighteen() {
});

/**
 * Function twenty.
 */
nineteen(function twenty() {
    /**
     * Function twentyTwo.
     */
    twentyOne(function twentyTwo() {
    });
});

/**
 * Function twentyThree.
 */
function twentyThree() {
}
```

JSDoc only picks up on function twentyThree. The rest are completely missed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never used JSDoc before, but from glancing at their documentation, I'm not sure why any of your stuff would work. I think you need to go back and read the docs for JSDoc. For example, I think `four` should be documented as a `@namespace` (same for your IIFE). And I think you need to use `@name` and `@lends` in specific places

Answer (score 5):

This is one example that will give you more output from JSDoc(3):

```
/**
 * Function one.
 * @namespace one
 */
(function one() {
    /**
     * Function two.
     * @namespace two
     * @memberof one
     */
    function two() {
        /**
         * Function three.
         * @memberof one.two
         */
        function three() {
        }
    }
})();
```